# Perl DBI login fail:SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

Description: I installed SQL Server 2012 on my local machine(Windows 7). At first I installed with  Windows authentication. After searching on web, I change to SQL Server authentication and set as: In SQL Server Management Studio->object explorer->security->logins->sa->right click property, select SQL Server authen and set password as "!Abcd1234!" for example.

Then I tried that I can connect by SQL Server authentication with sa/password using Management Studio. But using Perl script I failed.

My simple Perl script as below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use dbi;

my $user = "sa";
my $password = "!Abcd1234!";
my $connect = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;UID=$user;PWD=$password")or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

I got error

```
Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000)
```

May I get any help or trace method?

Yes, Mitch Wheat, I do enable "sa" account in the status tab. Sorry missing to mention that. I doubt whether my Perl script is correct? I think access locally should have no firewall issues right?

Answer (score 2):

I have connected many a times from perl (running on linux) to the MSSQL server. and while doing so, I would create a DSN manualy on the my Linux box and then write below syntax to connect:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ('dbi:ODBC:odbc-test', 'sqluser_name', 'sqluser_password');
```

Where, `odbc-test` is the name of the DSN

And it always worked.

unfortunately I never done any perl DBI connection from windows.

So,

On your windows box, could you create a DSN manually first and then follow above mentioned syntax to connect to the MSSQL server .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your method after successfully creating the DSN. Please see my issues in comments to Thai Heng.

Comment: Check if [this](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-odbc-osn/) is helpful.

Comment: It seems I encountered another question. I'll raise a new post.

Comment: I tried another remote SQL server and successfully created a DSN which using the Windows credential to login. I tested the DSN's connectivity to be successful and tried your Perl but not succeed for my case yet. I'm using Windows 7. And I use a domain prefixed sqluser_name, I think yours is the SQL authentication. The server didn't open a SQL authentication for me yet. But I think the DSN comprise the Windows authentication information and can connect fine, does the DBI->connect still need that username and password in your example?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. As I stated earlier, I always connected from Linux. So when I created DSN on Linux, it was SQL Authentication. Also, the `odbc.ini` that i created on Linux did not have any username/password info. Hence I had to explicitly provide it in my `DBI->connect` statement. I never had a chance to do this with Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should using **ODBC administrator** to test the connection first.

Comment: You're right. When setting-up new DSN by ODBC administrator, same error occurred. But I didn't now how to configure the "Client Configuration..." button. I choose local. Is the "Server Alias" and "Server name" still mandatory? And what I should input to?

Comment: I use "localhost" to  "Server name" and instance name to  "Server Alias" but still failed to create the DSN. The same error: SQL Server does not exist or access denied. Though I can login using SQL Server Management Studio.